# Linq Value cannot be null on FK

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Using C# MVC5 Visual studio 2015.

I have a method that contains the following code:

```
public List<OffersOnPropertyViewModel> Build(string buyerId)
    {
        var filtered = _context.Properties.Where(x => x.Offers.Any(c => c.BuyerUserId == buyerId)).ToList();
        var model = filtered.Select(c =>
        {
            var item = new OffersOnPropertyViewModel()
            {
               PropertyType = c.PropertyType,
               NumberOfBedrooms = c.NumberOfBedrooms,
               StreetName = c.StreetName,
               Offers = c.Offers.Where(d => d.BuyerUserId == buyerId).Select(x => new OfferViewModel
               {
                   Id = x.Id,
                   Amount = x.Amount,
                   CreatedAt = x.CreatedAt,
                   IsPending = x.Status == OfferStatus.Pending,
                   Status = x.Status.ToString(),
                   BuyerUserId = x.BuyerUserId
               }),
            };
            return item;
        }).ToList();
        //TODO: refactor, shorten linq, duping where clause
        return model;
    }
```

Here is the model:

```
    public class Property
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int NumberOfBedrooms { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SellerUserId { get; set; }

    public bool IsListedForSale { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

In the DB Offers table has the property id as its FK.

The method fails at runtime saying the Value cannot be null.

When I step through I notice the filtered results (in the example its 1 result), is saying offers is null. Although the query just filtered the results based on "x.Offers".

I simply need a way to retrieve a list of property's that have offers made by the buyerId provided.  Is my approach wrong? or am i missing a one liner?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add `Include()` to your LINQ query to bring in child objects, as follows:

```
var filtered = _context.Properties.Include("Offers")
    .Where(x => x.Offers.Any(c => c.BuyerUserId == buyerId)).ToList();
```

The reason your filter works with the `Any()` is because when generating the SQL query, this part forms the `WHERE` clause and is not included in the `SELECT`.

Comment: of course, completly forgot to bring in children via include....sigh that friday feeling